# Adding an image via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to make an image item from a url. I am uploading an image and showing it. I'm struggling with turning the url into an image.

The error i'm getting is;

[object%20File]:1 GET file:///D:/Uni/Uni/TM284/TMA%2003/TMA%2003%20zip%20file-20210209/[object%20File] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

My code;

```
function addImageEntry(key, url) {
// Create a image element
var imgElement = new Image();
imgElement.alt = "Photo entry";

// Load the image
imgElement.src = url;

// Add a section to the page containing the image
addSection(key, imgElement);
}

function addEntryClick() {
// Add an empty text entry, using the current timestamp to make a key
var key = "diary" + Date.now();
var text = "";
var isNewEntry = true;
addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry);
}

function addPhotoClick() {
// Trigger the 'click' event of the hidden file input element
// (as demonstrated in Block 3 Part 4)
var inputElement = document.querySelector("#image input");
inputElement.click();
}

function processFile(event) {
// Create an event listener to add an image entry
function addImage(url) {
    // Add a new image entry, using the current timestamp to make a key
    var key = "diary" + Date.now();
    addImageEntry(key, url);
    
    // TODO: Q1(c)(iv) Task 1 of 2
    // Make an image item using the given url
    // (demonstrated elsewhere in this file)                     
    
    var data = fileObject;
            
            
    // Store the item in local storage using the given key
    // (demonstrated elsewhere in this file)
    var item = makeItem("image", data);
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);
}

// Add a 'dummy' image entry 
//addImage(window.DUMMY_DATA_URL);

// TODO: Q1(c)(iv) Task 2 of 2
// Complete this function to read a file when it is selected:
// (reading files into a data URL using FileReader is demonstrated in Block 3 Part 4)
// (imgElement and messageElement do not exist in this app so remove that code)
// ...then call addImage using the data URL you obtain
// ...and comment out line above using window.DUMMY_DATA_URL

var reader = new FileReader();  
    
var img = event.target;
var fileObject = img.files[0];
reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject);

addImage(fileObject);



 
// Clear the file selection (allows selecting the same file again)
//inputElement.value = '';
 }
```

Comment: The path to your image is invalid.

Comment: Yeah, @flamesdev is totally right. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND means file isn't at the path you specified. I think you tried append File object to string, there's [object File]. And for browser, file protocol is useless

Comment: @TomášWróbel I don't think the file protocol is the cause of the problem as long as the webpage is being run locally.

Comment: As @TomášWróbel stated, you're just appending an object to a string. You likely want to access a specific property on the object and then append that value to the string, but it's difficult to tell without more context.

Comment: I'm selecting the image from a file location, this is then supplying the url. When i try to load the url its giving the error.